# Shunting-Yard function definitions

Tags: c++, parsing, shunting-yard

Does anyone have any insight on adding function *definition* support to a Shunting-Yard-based parser?

Single-statement definitions are simple. I can modify my parser to recurse inside of a block (that's very vague!) to handle function definitions as a sub-program, but that feels like a kludge.

Any better solutions?

**Update**

So, I managed to get this to work with surprisingly few modifications. The SY phase pushes both `{` and `}` onto the stack.

When the parser (next phase in the pipeline) encounters a `{` (blockstart), it creates a new `Block` (AST) structure and pushes it onto the RPN stack. When the parser reaches a `}`, it creates a vector of AST nodes, and pops the stack until it encounters a `Block`. At that point, the vector of nodes that were encountered between the block end and the block start are added to the Block's collection of expressions (statements).

When the parser reaches a Block on the stack, it checks to see if the next (lower on the stack) node is a function call. If so, it pops the function call, creates a function definition node, and uses the previously-generated block and call to define the function.

That's all a very vague/semi-useless description - [I will attempt to write up a detailed explanation and post it somewhere](http://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: It depends on how complicated your definition / block syntax is. If it is still an operator-precedence grammar, then the usual construction rules will Just Work.

Comment: @rici block syntax is C-ish, as in `{ expression; expression; ... }` I'm sure the imperfection is my own, but it doesn't Just Work. I'll attempt to generate a useful example. Alternatively: this is a rev 1 DSL, so redefining the block structure is possible if it'll make implementation more straightforward.

Comment: OK, maybe "Just Work" was a slight overstatement. But (1) you haven't explained what a definition looks like (are there types? is there a prototype? etc.) and (2) you do have do a *little* work. The S-Y algorithm has a point at which `{`...`;` is reduced, and at which `{`...`}` is reduced. The first one will append an expression to the accumulating definition; the second one will append an expression and then store the definition somewhere (that depends on how your declarations work). The handwaving doesn't include how you suppress evaluation; you need to do that, too.

Comment: @rici Good information, thanks. I managed to get it to work (see update if anyone is interested.)